# Clean mildew from inside interior paneling

Tags: cleaning, interior

My sunroof was left open during a rainstorm recently and the interior of the car got pretty soaking wet.  I was able to dry up most of the visible water.  However, a lot of water got inside the ceiling and dripped down the windshield crossbars.  The cloth ceiling was damp for a bit and now the next day reeks of musty mildew.  What is the best way to try and clean inside the ceiling paneling?  Obviously, anything I put down there can't really be vacuumed up afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way is to remove the interior trim to clean it and make certain it is completely dry before  you reinstall it.  This is not a job for the faint of heart.

Comment: so basically, I have to take it to a dealer to clean it for me, is what you're saying?

Comment: I have pulled the interior out of several cars and even gotten them back in.  I just takes a lot of time.  If you don't want to do that, then try calling a good detailing shop, they may do it.  Tell the person who left the sunroof open to help pay for it.